# Send broadcast in Service & receive it in AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

In my **project**, when `Service` started, I send a broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.service.action");
intent.setPackage("com.my.project.test"); //only broadcast to my test project
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
Log.i("tag","broadcast is sent!");
```

In my **test project** `AndroidTestCase`, I start & bind the `Service`, which triggers the broadcast sending too. So, I decided to receive this broadcast also in my `AndroidTestCase`:

```
public class MyTestCase extends AndroidTestCase{ 
  ...
  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
     //This is working fine, I can see the broadcast is sent log in service
     bindToService() 

     //register broadcast receiver 
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("my.service.action");
     getContext().registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, filter);
  }

  public BroadcastReceiver mMyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //BUT the broadcast sent in service is not received in my test case, why?
      Log.i(TAG, "Received in test case!");

     }  
 };
}
```

As you can see, I have registered a broadcast receiver in my `AndroidTestCase` of test project. Though the broadcast was sent in `Service` of my project, but it is not received. Why?

**==========UPDATE===========**

After I removed this line:`intent.setPackage("com.my.project.test")` when sending broadcast,  my receiver in `AndroidTestCase` class is receiving the broadcast now.

But now, I am wondering why explicitly set package for intent blocks the receiver in **test project**, even though the package name I set is my **test project**. In **AndroidManifest.xml** of my test project, I have my package name definition:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.project.test"
   ...
```

Comment: `AndroidTestCase` is a `Service`, `Activity` or what?

Comment: It is a general test case class in Android test framework: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html  . The Service I mentioned is in my project not test project.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
     //This is working fine, I can see the broadcast is sent log in service
     bindToService() 

     //register broadcast receiver 
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("my.service.action");
     getContext().registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, filter);
  }
```

Change  To:

```
@Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();

     //register broadcast receiver 
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("my.service.action");
     getContext().registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, filter);

   //This is working fine, I can see the broadcast is sent log in service
     bindToService();

  }
```

Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842517/broadcast-receiver-class-and-registerreceiver-method/18842810#18842810) answer.Hope it will help u!!

Comment: Actually, it is not because of the order in the code, I have intent.setPackage("com.my.project.test"), after I removed this line, it works fine, my receiver in AndroidTestCase class is receiving the broadcast now. But now, I am wondering why explicitly set the package for intent blocks the receiver...