# onPostExecute in AsyncTask with BroadcastReceiver is throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

When the new message is received, message should be passed to the internet for my further business logic.

To receive the new messages I used onReceive of broadcastreceiver and to process the internet business logics in background I used AsyncTask.

I am getting the null pointer exception in onPostExecute method of AyncTask, I read many stackoverflow and other website solutions and created the interface and initialized it in the AsyncTask extended class constructor. But getting only nullpointer.

My Full code:

MainActivity:

```
public class SmsActivity extends Activity implements     ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete {
private static SmsActivity inst;
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
public static SmsActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
}

@Override
public void processResp(String output){
    String outpu1 = output+" in main";
}
```

}

BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
    if (intentExtras != null) {
        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
        String smsMessageStr = "";

        boolean rechargeResult = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
            String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
            smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                if (smsBody != null) {
                    String[] splitValues = smsBody.split(" ");
                    if (splitValues != null && splitValues.length > 0) {
                        String siteURL = "SITE_URL";
                        try {
                            ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete procesInterf = null;
                            ParseURL urlParse = new ParseURL(procesInterf);
                            Toast.makeText(context, siteURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            new ParseURL(procesInterf).execute(new String[]{siteURL});
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "123 "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "split values is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "smsbody is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

ParseURL:

```
public class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


ProgressDialog progressDialog;

OnAsyncRequestComplete caller;
//Context context;


public ParseURL(OnAsyncRequestComplete a) {
    caller = a;
   // context = a;
}

public interface OnAsyncRequestComplete {
    public void processResp(String response);
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog.setMessage("WAIT...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String responseStatus = "";
    try {
        if(strings!=null) {
            if (null != strings[0]) {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).timeout(0).get();
                if (doc != null) {
                    String result = doc.select("body").text();

                    if (null != result) {

                        if (result.toLowerCase().contains("FAILED".toLowerCase())) {
                            responseStatus = result;
                        } else if (result.toLowerCase().contains("SUCCESS".toLowerCase())) {
                            responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
                        } else {
                            responseStatus = "FAILED";
                        }
                    } else {
                        responseStatus = "google";
                    }
                } else {
                    responseStatus = "facebook";
                }
            } else {
                responseStatus = "youtube";
            }
        }else{
            responseStatus = "ebay";
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseStatus;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    caller.processResp(s);
}
```

}

I tried many solutions which is shared in the stackoverflow and other sites. But I could not solve it. Please do not mark this as duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A question reporting a null pointer exception should include the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 1):

Ohh maaan...

```
ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete procesInterf = null;
ParseURL urlParse = new ParseURL(procesInterf);
```

---

```
   public ParseURL(OnAsyncRequestComplete a) {
        caller = a;
    }
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    caller.processResp(s);
}
```

Are You see mistake?

You pass null to the ParseUrl constructor, so on PosteExecute() tries to call a method of a null callback.

I suspect that you would like to do that

```
ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete procesInterf = SmsActivity.this;
```

But it will work, if your SmsBroadcastReceiver class is a inner class of SmsActivity.

Comment: Chris Stratton, I am write above for problem, and illustrated it by code. Or do you mean my bad English?

Comment: Thanks that is a little better, though something like "You pass null to the ParseUrl constructor, so onPostExecute() tries to call a method  of a null callback" would be clearer.

Comment: sirelon, when I try  ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete procesInterf = SmsActivity.this; in SmsBroadCastRecevier.java i am getting the compilation error like "is not an enclosing class". And you mentioned like it will work if it would have been a inner class of smsactivity. Can you share me the snippet to try.

Comment: You need to initialize procesInterf. Not null! Easy way be a this:
`ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete procesInterf = new OnAsyncRequestComplete(){
@Override
public void processResp(String output){
    String outpu1 = output+" in main";
}`

Comment: That to use inner broadcastreciever you need to register broadcast in your activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `caller`. Basically you set it to `null`, then you pass it to your `AsyncTask`, then you try to use it.

You already use the singleton pattern in your Activity, so you were probably after

`ParseURL.OnAsyncRequestComplete procesInterf = SmsActivity.instance();`

Comment: please share me the sample code that what need to be changed and tried.

Comment: @NaveenkumarGunasekaran Where do you register that `BroadcastReceiver` ?

Comment: I implemented the interface to process the onPostExecute result further

Comment: `<receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: I understand your intention, however your `BroadcastReceiver` has no knowledge of your `Activity` (which is where your implementation of the interface is. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @NaveenkumarGunasekaran I think I understood your intention now. Give that a try.

Comment: Thrasher: I changed the code like you mentioned but still i am getting this toast, `Toast.makeText(context, "123 "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` printing 123null

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: Ah, of course, what was I thinking. You'll probably have to register the `BroadcastReceiver` manually in your `Activity`. Create a field in your activity that holds your `BroadcastReceiver`, instantiate it in `onCreate()` and `register` and `unregister` it. See this answer for how to register / unregister: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18842810/1991295

Comment: @NaveenkumarGunasekaran Add a comment if you still need help with the new approach. :P

Comment: @Thrasher: i updated like this,but no luck: `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
        filter1 = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter1);
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }`

Comment: @NaveenkumarGunasekaran Are you still getting the same error or is it something else now?

Comment: @Thrasher: Still getting the same null pointer exception. I do not know whats the mistake I am doing really.