# Disable/Enable BroadcastReceiver when needed

Tags: java, android

In my application I need to receive an activation code from SMS when user registered. For that I have a `BroadcastReceiver` but I don't want in to always enabled and I need it just once when user is registering. How to do that?

Comment: You can use local broadcast receiver register in single class. Or you can put condition to check on receiver. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842517/broadcast-receiver-class-and-registerreceiver-method/18842810#18842810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call registerReceiver and unregisterReceiver in your activity. Here is an example of it :

```
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

where receiver is your broadcast receiver class and filter will be

```
private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```

incase of sms receiver.

You can call registerReceiver once you require to receive a sms and call unregisterReceiver to stop listening for incoming sms.

Comment: but without registering it is working. i want it to be disabled untill i register it

Comment: So have you register that in Manifest file ?

Comment: oh i get it now let me try it

Comment: Don't register your broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest file. Register it run time. I mean call registerReceiver once you require it .

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to register the Broadcast Receiver in the activity; it will remain alive only for that instance of activity. Instead of registering it in manifest just register in the activity on runtime when required.

Comment: how to register receiver without defining it in manifest? please post code

Comment: you can check this answer for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver

Comment: You can check this tutorial to understand both ways: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html