# Major difference between registerReceiver() and sendBroadCast() to call the BroadCast Receivers?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

When I am working with broadcast receivers, I get a little confused about methods like **sendBroadcast** and **registerReciever**. Both gives the same result, and working functionality are also the same. But, what is the reason behind to work with both?

For example, If I try to get the result of my battery level, I am using the coding like

```
public void onButtonClick(View view)
{
IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
BraodcastReceiver br=new BroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(br,intentFilter);
}
```

or

```
public void onButtonClick(View view)
{
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

What are the differences between this two methods? How they will work? Can you please give me the reasons?

My BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcastClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
       Log.d("BatteryLevel",level);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842517/broadcast-receiver-class-and-registerreceiver-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to understand what is broadcast receiver in android.

[This one example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

I will explain shortly.

The first example is registering as the name indicates. So after registering a particular broadcast , it will listen for any broadcast with that **ACTION** you provided with **intentFilter**. The working is same as the callback mechanism.

The second example is **sending broadcast** . Sending broadcast means you broadcast something, say battery change(OS Level) ,It will broadcast with an **ACTION**.

SO send broadcast will send some data with **Action** , if we listen a broadcast with **Action** then it will trigger on BroadcastRecicver class

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go through the developer docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

you will get the clear idea.

**coming to your question**

`registerReceiver()` is used to register your broadcast receiver to a particular action eg- `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` or you can define your own.

What it mean is that whenever any APP will send a broadcast (send using a `sendBroadcast()` method) to this action your broadcast receivers `onReceive()` method will get called.