# Broadcast receiver for internet connection does not work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create an application that tracks internet connection. When internet connectivity status changes, it should make a toast. For this, I am supposed to use Broadcast Receiver. So far, I've written (found) this code (following code only includes parts related to this job)

```
ConnectivityReceiver mConnectivityReceiver;
IntentFilter mConnectivityIntentFilter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    mConnectivityIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mConnectivityIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE);

    mConnectivityReceiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();
    ....
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver, mConnectivityIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver);
}

public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("onreceive", "success");

        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean isWifiConn = false;
        boolean isMobileConn = false;
        for (Network network : connMgr.getAllNetworks()) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(network);
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                isWifiConn |= networkInfo.isConnected();
            }
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                isMobileConn |= networkInfo.isConnected();
            }
        }

        if (isMobileConn || isWifiConn) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection lost, may cause some functions to not work properly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have these two permissions in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I tried on both emulator (Android 8.0) and device (Android 5.1), my code doesn't work. It doesn't make a toast and it doesn't even create the log.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you add manifest receiver ?

Comment: @alirezadaryani I thought I don't need a manifest entry when I register it in code. But I added this entry to manifest to see if it works, problem remains. Is this entry correct?

`<receiver android:name=".activities.MainActivity$ConnectivityReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: its correct and i cant get where you get issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit, but I think you need the `intent-filter` in your manifest as well (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18842810/2740650)).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this if you just want to do something simple when the connectivity changes, there is a much easier solution.

Create BroadCast Receiver inside your activity :

```
private BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        doSomethingOnNetworkChange(ni);
    }
};
```

Then in onResume and onPause do the registration:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new 
    IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Should I also do something with the manifest.xml?

Comment: Have you registered broadcast in mainfest :        <receiver android:name=".networkStateReceiver"></receiver>